# Immediate Alert on set parameters

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I applied manually Buy and SL prices in the INPUT forms.
Further conditions are there when to trigger alets on next levels, that is fine.

But I want very first (Initial) Alert immediate after alert placed in the Trading view system.
For a
Buy Price
SL Price
Symbol
Date

This is for record when I took order in my email and placed my Alert.